Converting MP3 to BASE64 changes the format to WEBM?
I am using an API that receives base64 and any format. I should send mp3 format base64 but during conversion in the function below whatever ways I try it changes the format from mp3 to webm during conversion. What to do so the original format should remain as mp3?
    async function audioToBase64(latestAudioBlob) {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onerror = reject;
        reader.onload = (e) => resolve(e.target.result.split(',')[1]);
        reader.readAsDataURL(latestAudioBlob);
      });
    }

Even I have tried this but it also did not help:
    async function audioToBase64(latestAudioBlob) {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onerror = reject;
        reader.onload = (e) => {
          const arrayBuffer = e.target.result;
          const base64String = btoa(String.fromCharCode(...new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer)));
          resolve(base64String);
        };
        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(latestAudioBlob);
      });
    }


I have checked my audio I have the recorder function in my code set the blob to mp3. Audio is great, before conversion is mp3 but after conversion changes to webm.
What to do?
This one did not work when I wrote in vs code editor:
    async function audioToBase64(latestAudioBlob) {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onerror = reject;
        reader.onload = (e) => resolve(e.target.result);
        reader.readAsBinaryString(latestAudioBlob);
      });
    }


Does this help in any way?
